# How to install GIMP resynthesizer on Mac OS?

Tags: install

I'm running El Capitain and have GIMP installed but can't figured out how to install the resynthesizer. I copied the files from the linux version of the plugin into the plugin folder of GIMP but GIMP does not seem to detect it.

Comment: Linux plugins won't work on Mac.

Answer (score 6):

To add some approaches not covered in @LangLangC's answer:

1. Using Homebrew you can run `brew cask install lisanet-gimp` to get a version of GIMP with some parts of the resynthesizer ready to go, including the most important `Filters > Enhance > Heal selection`. This suffers from the same problem as the lisanet offerings in @LangLangC's answer: it is out of date. For example, there is no support for .HEIF files.
2. There are now prebuilt Mac versions of the Resynthesizer and other plugins available at https://github.com/aferrero2707/gimp-plugins-collection/releases/tag/continuous. There is a thorough tutorial on how to install the files from this site [here](https://daviesmediadesign.com/how-to-download-and-install-gimp-resynthesizer-for-mac/).
   In short you download the current version of the plug-in (currently [ResynthesizerPlugin-Gimp-2.10-osx.tgz](https://github.com/aferrero2707/gimp-plugins-collection/releases/download/continuous/ResynthesizerPlugin-Gimp-2.10-osx.tgz)), extract it, and put the extracted files in your plug-ins directory, which may be inside your application bundle. (`/Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins`)

I also had to Ctrl+right-click on the `resynthesizer` and `resynthesizer-gui` executables in the Finder and tell OS X it was okay to open them despite the fact that they were downloaded from the internet before everything worked.

To avoid these GateKeeper hurdles, run this command before installing the files:

```
xattr -csrv ~/Downloads/ResynthesizerPlugin-Gimp-2.10-osx
```

(Obviously, the path used in that command to remove the downloads-are-dangerous-flag should reflect the actual location of your files…)

Comment: Confirmed to be a nice solution! Upvote this answer!

Comment: Improvement suggestion: add the howto for (2), currently only linked, but adapt the path to not go into app-bundle but AppiicationSupport folder?

Comment: #2 works for me but I had to make a symbolic link to "fake" having a newer dynamically linked library. `cd /usr/local/lib` then `ln -s libintl.8.dylib libintl.9.dylib`. Major thanks to http://homepage.agrl.ethz.ch/eugsterw/knowhow/gimp-resynthesizer/

Comment: I used the GitHub link from #2 and followed the instructions there. It works, I didn’t have any GateKeeper hurdles, and this solution should survive minor upgrades of GIMP itself.

Answer (score 5):

There are currently two relatively easy ways to get to this plugin. "Easy" as in "still a pain", just like the other, third and fourth option.

1. <del>The batteries included approach, as recommended b resynthesizer: download a build from [GIMP on OS X](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html). Sadly development seems to have stopped about a year ago. Currently the latest version is 2.8.12 built for Sierra.</del> (Original website no longer active as of May 2019. On Sourceforge the version [recommended by Resynthesizer](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) [Gimp on OSX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimponosx/) [Gimp-2.8.18p1-Sierra.dmg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimponosx/files/latest/download) 2017-01-08)
2. The 'some plugins already included approach: download a binary from [Partha, Photography and Related Musings](https://www.partha.com). Does not include the resynthesizer plugin itself but has recent builds against which building the plugin itself is a bit easier. Latest builds available. Currently at [McGimp 2.10.8 Standard Edition (2019)](https://www.partha.com/downloads/McGimp-2.10.8.app.zip).
3. Use the help of [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) to [build](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gimp) everything [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) from scratch/source including all build-dependencies and then  go to GIMP [Resynthesizer Plugin Suite](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) and build that as well from source.
4. Install the official or any other binary for GIMP as usual on macOS, then install a virtual machine and a Linux in that, with GIMP and the resynthesizer plugin ready-made to play well from a package repository. Use that for the Enhance filters (if you work exclusively in the Virtual Machine you might of yourse skip the macOS part of installing GIMP)

That said, its probably easiest (and a huge hassle) to just install two versions of GIMP, like in the 4th option. A recent one without the plugin but all the latest core features, and either an older GIMP with plugin, or the GIMP on VM route.

Comment: Your first point, the download link is broken. Your second point, can't find the binary

Answer (score 4):

"Resynthesizer"
I've been chasing my tail like a dog all afternoon over this.

Gimp update 2.9.22 update promptly deleted any signs of "Resynthesizer"; healing is gone.
As a plugin, the Mac version is not available because it is part of some modified version. I believe mine was McGimp.
Downloaded McGimp (2.9.7), it's not included.
I looked and saw no early versions of any custom modifications stating it was included. libregraphicsworld.org: nothing.

"Resynthesizer" for Mac does not exist any more.

It is total bs when they claim Gimp had "Content Aware" years before Photoshop. Um, no. There was a plug-in for Gimp, requiring a grad student programmer to install it, but no one thought it was important enough to make it a standard filter or fill function.
I searched all over. There are dozens of tutorials on how to use it, usually boasting "we're first" ad nauseam, but no one mentioned where I can download and install it in a Mac, manually or otherwise.

Gimp may have had the plug-in floating around somewhere, but Photoshop had it installed and easy to use in a logical location.
[No, I do not work for Adobe, otherwise I wouldn't be trying to find it for Gimp.]

Gimp, still doesn't have it; neither do I.
Time to have a beer.

Comment: This instructions for building from source [here](https://gist.github.com/ryan-robeson/5841f712ff23c910bbbfac793c16bfad) worked for me (macOS 10.14.6, GIMP 2.10.10 from gimp.org)

Answer (score 1):

This version seems to have the plugin built and included:

http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/News/News.html

Comment: Server Error
404
Page Not Found
This page either doesn't exist, or it moved somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Several things I had to work out. First is make sure you are in your usr Library Gimp folder and not in the Application Contents folder.

Second, after you put any .py in the plugin folder you have to "turn it on". Mac does this to protect you. Open Terminal and go to the folder where the plugin is, then type "chmod u+x " This will give the plugin execute rights. For example "chmod u+x plugin-heal-selection.py". Then start Gimp and it should be there!